# Nodejs - how to upload file from req to aws s3

Tags: node.js, file, amazon-s3

Working on web-app: React & Node.

the client app sends file to the server, and the server should upload it to an `S3 bucket`.

using `import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';` i found the `upload` function.

The `upload` function expect to get Buffer or Stream, and i don't know how to convert the file to buffer/stream.

**Code**

```
app.get('/upload', (req, res) => {
   const { file } = req;
   s3.upload({ Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET', Key: 'MY_KEY', Body: streamifyFile(file)});
})

const streamifyFile = () => {
   // how to implement
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
const uploadToS3 = async (req) => {
  const {
    file
  } = req.body;
  const { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
    Key: `${context.user.email}/${new Date().toISOString()}.${filename}`,
    Body: pass,
  };
  const uploadPromise = s3.upload(params).promise();
  const streamInput: Stream = createReadStream();
  streamInput.pipe(pass);
  const uploadData = await uploadPromise;
  logger.info(
    `Successfully upload - file: ${filename}, location: ${uploadData.Location}`,
  );
};
```